# About a weak$^*$ convergent net

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group and $A$ be semisimple commutative Banach algebra such that $A^{**}$ has Radon-Nikodym property. Denote by $\Gamma$ and $M(G)$ the dual group and the measure algebra of $G$, resp.. Let $(f_i)$ be a net in $M(G)\hat\otimes A^{**}\cong(C_0(G,A^*))^*$ which is weak$^*$-convergent to $f$. Also, assume that $(f_i)$ conveges pointwise to a continuous function on $\Gamma\times\Delta(A)$. Here $C_0$ denotes the set of continuous functions vanish at infinity, "$*$" and "$**$" stands for the first and the second dual, resp. by $\hat\otimes$ we denote the projective tensor product, and $\Delta(A)$ is the Gelfand spectrum of $A$. Is it true that $$\lim_i\langle f_i,\xi\otimes\phi\rangle=\langle f,\xi\otimes\phi\rangle$$
where $\xi\in\Gamma$, $\phi\in\Delta(A)$?

Comment: Isn't this false with $A=\mathbb C$?  E.g. take $G=\mathbb Z$ and consider the sequence of point masses $(\delta_n)$.  This is weak$^*$-null, as paired against any $f\in c_0(\mathbb Z)$ with have $\langle \delta_n, f \rangle = f(n) \rightarrow 0$.  But paired against $f=1$ (constant function) we get $\langle \delta_n, f \rangle = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thank you for the comment, you are right, so I edit the question to state all my assumptions in my problem.

Comment: The dual of $C_0(G,A^*)$ is the space of vector measures $M(G, A^{**})$, which is in general not the projective tensor product $M(G) \hat\otimes_\pi A^{**}$.

Comment: Are you sure that $M(G) \hat\otimes X^*$ is equal to $C_0(G, X)^*$? I would expect this to be false for a general infinite-dimensional Banach space X and G non-discrete

Comment: @YemonChoi I think so, because $M(G)$ has both the approximation property and Radon–Nikodym property.

Comment: I'm afraid $M(G)$ fails the RNP unless $G$ is discrete.

Comment: @DirkWerner If it is, so I have to add the assumption that $A^{**}$ has RNP to ensure the isomorphism holds.